# How to identify repeated characters using a regex?

Tags: regex, sed

This question regards a regex puzzle. I have a list of words with repeated characters, e.g.

```
stubbornness
raccoon
cooccurred
successful
```

Notice each of the terms has two sets of repeared letters, e.g. "bb", in "stubbornness". I have already written my script (in ruby), and I am able to solve my task using per-character iteration in a code loop.

However, this puzzling task caught my eye... I wonder if it can be done using a regex? I have already consulting regex tutorials, and other StackOverflow questions, but I can't figure out how to report the duped character. Here's the desired output:

```
bb stubbornness
cc raccoon
oo cooccurred
cc successful
```

with the first set of repeated letters in the front. I have tried to write my own regex (with sed on MacOS; use -r on Ubuntu instead of -E) for this:

```
sed -E 's#(.*?)(.)\2(.*)#\2\2 \1\2\2\3#g'
```

But that has an invalid repetition-operator operand. Any ideas? Note the repeated characters could be anywhere in the string.

Comment: Do you have to use regex? i would just read characters and the first duplicate I find, I will return that.

Comment: No. Of course not. That's basically what I did already. It's easy with a small loop processing a text string. But I asked myself... can it be done with a regex?

Comment: Why is `sed` so important?

Comment: sed itself is not important, it's just how I usually do my regex on the command line since it's so concise. I tried using awk (see comment below), but I did something wrong.

Comment: Use a language, while( strin.search ( '/(.)\1/',match ) {push(ary, match);} if (ary.size()) {strout = join(' ', ary) + ' ' + strin;}

Answer (score 2):

Try this RegEx:

```
(.*?)((\w)\3)(.*)
```

Substituting with:

```
\2 \1\2\4
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/uS2oR6/1)</kbd>

---

Thanks to **@Kent** who informed my that sed does not support lazy `.*?`, I came up with this new RegEx:

```
(
(?!(\w)\2)       # DO NOT Match if there are double letters
.                # Data before dobule letters
)*
((\w)\4)         # Double Letter
(.*)             # Data after letters

# SHORTER REGEX (1 LINE)
((?!(\w)\2).)*((\w)\4)(.*)
```

Substitute with:

```
\3 \0
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/uS2oR6/1)</kbd>

Comment: sed doesn't support "non-greedy"

Comment: Ah... that's why the .*? was failing?

Comment: So if sed does not support non-greedy, I tried this -- but it didn't match anything.  awk '{ gsub(/(.*?)((\w)\3)(.*)/, "\2 \1\2\4"); print }'  What did I do wrong?

Comment: @user6138212 awk doesn't support `.*?` either

Comment: @user6138212 I updated my answer with a new way to do this (essentially it creates a lazy for sed, by not selecting the characters the next group will match)

Comment: @EdMorton The OP says *"sed itself is not important"* in the `4th` comment on his question. The OP is replying to **@sln**. So apart from the fact that my answer is right since he/she does not necessarily need `sed`, I also have the version for if the OP **does** need to use `sed`. So what is the problem?

Comment: Neither of the regexps you posted will work in any version of sed. Nor will they work in any version of awk. I don't know which tool(s) they would work in and I doubt if the OP wants to copy/paste their files into an online tool every time they want to manipulate them so, to make your answer much more useful and avoid people wasting time trying to use your regexps in various tools that they can't work in such as sed or awk, please edit your answer to show a regexp working in the context of some command-line tool that the OP (or anyone else) might reasonably use to manipulate their input files.

Answer (score 1):

if you have **gnu sed**, this one-liner (with help of `rev`, which is member of unix-util) works:

```
 sed -r 's/.*(.)\1.*/echo "\1\1 $(echo \0|rev)"/ge' <(rev file)
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
stubbornness
raccoon
cooccurred
successful

kent$  sed -r 's/.*(.)\1.*/echo "\1\1 $(echo \0|rev)"/ge'  <(rev f)
bb stubbornness
cc raccoon
oo cooccurred
cc successful
```

Comment: That works with sed -E or sed -r on Ubuntu, but not on macOS where the /e substitution flag does not appear to be available. Only /Ngpw (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html)

Comment: So how did you get the `.*` to be non-greedy ?

Comment: I wrote clearly gnu sed. It has nothing todo with distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Here's an imperfect solution. Do your words always have 2 sets of repeated letters? If so, this will report the second to last, which in your case is the first:

```
sed 's#\(.*\)\(.\)\2\(.*\)\(.\)\4#\2\2 &#'
```

Note, there's no extended regex (no `-r`/`-E` for sed) here. But sorry, I don't know how to detect just the first occurrence. The \4 forces the \2 to detect the second to last. If you omit this: `\(.*\)\(.\)\4` then it would report just the final pair of repeated letters.

Answer (score 0):

How's this with rev and GNU sed for `-r`?

```
$ rev file | sed -r 's/(.*((.)\3).*)/& \2/' | rev
bb stubbornness
cc raccoon
oo cooccurred
cc successful
```

FWIW here's how I'd really solve the problem using a standard UNIX tool as opposed to Ruby, say, and as opposed to trying to solve it with a regexp in sed:

```
$ awk -v FS= '{p=""; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i==p) {print p $i, $0; next} p=$i } }' file
bb stubbornness
cc raccoon
oo cooccurred
cc successful
```

Some awks won't split a line into characters given a null FS so this is the portable version that will work in all awks:

```
$ awk '{p=""; for (i=1;i<=length($0);i++) { c=substr($0,i,1); if (c==p) {print p c, $0; next} p=c } }' file
bb stubbornness
cc raccoon
oo cooccurred
cc successful
```

Comment: That's clean. Works on Ubuntu with sed -r (or sed -E), but not on MacOS with sed -E. On the Mac, it has no effect, the output matches the input.

Comment: Maybe MacOS sed doesn't support backreferences in the matching regexp section? idk... I updated my answer to show how I'd really solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perl is your friend:

```
> perl -ne 'print @_[0,0], " $_" if (@_ = /(.)\1/g) > 1' < words.txt
bb stubbornness
cc raccoon
oo cooccurred
cc successful
>
```

This will print nothing for any input words that don't contain at least two sets of double letters.  And it's not much more work to list all the doubles found in a word.  And easily tweaked for triple sets:

```
> perl -ne 'print @_[0,0], " $_" if (@_ = /(.)\1/g) > 2' < wordlist.txt
ss Mississippi
ss Mississippian
ll Tallahassee
nn Tennessee
dd addressee
tt bitterroot
oo bookkeep
mm committee
```

If you're only searching for at least a single pair of double letters, then the problem becomes simpler:

```
perl -ne 'print "$& $_" if /(.)\1/' < wordlist.txt | tail
ll yellowish
ll you'll
tt ytterbium
tt yttrium
cc yucca
gg zigzagging
oo zoo
oo zoology
oo zoom
cc zucchini
```